# How to use use flask-caching decorator @cache on an external module class

Tags: python, flask, caching, python-decorators, flask-caching

**Context:**
I have flask application, which is an NGINX authentication module, written in flask, and in some part of the code I am making a call to an LDAP server.

The objective is to use flask-caching library to cache the response from the LDAP server and avoid that costly call.

The code bellow its a very stripped down version showing only the relevant sections.

**Problem**
In the below scenario I can't use the decorator `@cache.memoized` on a method of the Ldap class, as the variable `cache` is not available in that module.

```
name 'cache' is not defined
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask  
from flask_caching import Cache
from ldap import Ldap

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = Cache(app)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
@auth.login_required
def index(path):
    code = 200
    msg = "Another LDAP Auth"
    headers = [('x-username', getRegister('username')),
               ('x-groups', getRegister('matchedGroups'))]
    return msg, code, headers

@auth.verify_password
def login(username, password):
    ldap = Ldap()
    ldap.verifyUser(username, password)
```

**ldap.py**

```
class Ldap: 
    @cache.memoized(timeout=300)            <<<< error 
    def validateUser(self, username, password)
        if <ldap query goes here>
            return True
        return False
```

**Research**
The weird thing for me here is that this decorator depends on an object instance and not on a class as so many other scenarios I've seen

**Alternative:**
Definitively if I put the definition of the class in the same `main.py` and bellow the definition of the `cache` variable it works, however this will make my `main.py` file too long.

**Attempt 1:**
Trying to import my module after the definition of the cache variable has the same error

**Attempt 2:**
doing `from main import cache` inside `ldap.py` creates a circular import error.

**Idea:**
Pass the `cache` variable to the Ldap Class constructor and "somehow" use it to decorate the method, but I could not find how to do it exactly.